# I want to use subfigure in a multicol environment

Tags: subfloats, multicol, subfig

I want to add subfigures to get a 3 wide image as in the below image. When I attempt to use subfigure, it comes up with the error "Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' environment!."

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\title{Condensed Product Safety Card}
\author{Jacob}
\date{February 2018}

\begin{document}

\section*{{\normalfont Condensed Product  Safety Card}}

\hrulefill

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{100P Screen Wash}
3.1C, 6.1E, 6.3B, 6.4A 6.8B, 6.9B, 9.1B

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \mbox{
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width = 0.3cm]{Images/Hazard_symbols/24_flammable.jpg}}\quad
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.3cm]{Images/Hazard_symbols/6_irritant.jpg}}\quad
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.3cm]{Images/Hazard_symbols/9_ecotoxic.jpg}}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The error message -- specifically, the "floats not allowed in a multicols environment" part -- should point you toward the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for a decade or more. Don't use it. Use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.
- There seems to be no need, though, for either the `subfigure` or the `figure` machinery: Your code doesn't feature any `\caption` directives, and the figures aren't supposed to "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word).
- If you embed the three `\includegraphics` statements in a `center` environment, everything seems to work out ok. I would use a relative width, such as `0.3\columnwidth`, rather than an absolute width, such as `0.3cm`. (Aside: Are the individual graphs really supposed to be just 3mm wide?)
- A separate issue: You need `\noindent` before `\hrulefill`.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}

\section*{\normalfont Condensed Product Safety Card}

\noindent \hrulefill

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section*{100P Screen Wash}

3.1C, 6.1E, 6.3B, 6.4A 6.8B, 6.9B, 9.1B

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{Images/Hazard_symbols/24_flammable.jpg}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{Images/Hazard_symbols/6_irritant.jpg}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{Images/Hazard_symbols/9_ecotoxic.jpg}
\end{center}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```